# jQuery selector UL that contains NO LIs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-lists

Assuming the following HTML how can I find all uls that do NOT contain any lis? IE: In this case ul3 and ul4?

I can see that jQuery has the "has" selector but I can't see the inverse of it? Nor do I understand how I could combine has and not to accomplish what I need.

```
<div id="div1">
    <ul id='ul1'>
        <li>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul id='ul2'>
        <li>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul id='ul3'>
    </ul>

    <ul id='ul4'>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you have a list without items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nor do I understand how I could combine has and not to accomplish what I need.

As far as I can tell, it's as simple as:

```
$('ul:not(:has(li))')
```

Comment: :) I tested it on the jQuery documentation page for :not. However, **every** `ul` has an `li` on that page, so to be sure, I also tried with `p` and `strong`. The problem with your version is that `contains` is not appropriate here and `has` is; `contains` looks for a text string within the text descendants of the `ul`, not a child tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector (if you are sure there are no text node descendent too).

```
$('ul:empty');
```

Otherwise you could use...

```
$('ul').filter(function() { return ! $(this).find('li').length; });
```